# Creating a wordvector model combining words from other models

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word2vec, gensim

I have two different word vector models created using word2vec algorithm . Now issue i am facing is few words from first model is not there in second model . I want to create a third model from two different word vectors models where i can use word vectors from both models without loosing meaning and the context of word vectors.

Can I do this, and if so, how?

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could potentially translate the vectors for the words only in one model to the other model's coordinate space, using other shared words to learn a translation-function.

There's a facility to do this in recent gensim versions – see the [TranslationMatrix](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/translation_matrix.html) tool. There's a demo Jupyter notebook included in the `docs/notebooks` directory, viewable online at:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/translation_matrix.ipynb

You'd presumably take the *larger* model (or whichever one is thought to be *better*, perhaps because it was trained on more data), and translate the smaller number of words its missing into its space. You'd use as many common-reference 'anchor' words as is practical.